# Duda sobre MVC + DAO en JAVA

Tags: java, mvc, patrones-de-diseño

Buen día, quería preguntar sobre que tan "Obligatorio" es usar un controlador por cada vista y NO un controlador para todas las vistas.

Mi problema es que estuve realizando una práctica donde nos solicitaron implementar los patrones de diseño  *MVC + DAO* en Java y lo estuve realizando creando solo un controlador para todas las vistas.

Quería saber si lo que hice va en contra del patrón MVC.

En general mi proyecto (*Netbeans*) quedo así:

- > **controller**
  >
  > Controller.java
- > **model**
  >
  > Main.java (El que manda a llamar al controlador)
  >
  > Conexion.java (conexion a la bd)
  >
  > Cliente.java
  >
  > ClienteDAO.java
  >
  > Venta.java
  >
  > VentasDAO.java
  >
  > IMetodos.java (Esta fue una interface que contiene métodos `crud` que retornan un `booleano`)
- > **view**
  >
  > InsertView
  >
  > ...
  >
  > ...

Y otra duda, ¿La clase *Conexion.java* y *Main.java* si van en ese paquete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si estás implementando un patrón de diseño como lo es MVC (*Model-View-Controller*) o DAO (*Data Access Object*) lo mejor es seguir sus especificaciones ya que son consideradas buenas prácticas que contemplan buena estructura de código, mantenimiento, entre otras.

> Qué tan "Obligatorio" es usar un controlador por cada vista y NO un controlador para todas las vistas

No es obligatorio pero es lo deseable ya que es mejor aspirar a tener alta cohesión y bajo acoplamiento entre clases, es decir, que cada clase tenga una determinada función y solo a eso se dedique.

> ¿La clase *Conexion.java* y *Main.java* si van en ese paquete?

Pueden funcionar adecuadamente ahí donde se encuentran pero lo más recomendable sería trasladarlas a una mejor ubicación acorde a su objetivo. En el caso de la clase *Main.java* suele ir en la raíz de tu proyecto y *Conexion.java* en algún paquete como por ejemplo `config`.

Por ejemplo:

```
com
 +- example
     +- myapplication
         +- Main.java
         |
         +- config
         |   +- Conexion.java
         +- dao
         |   +- ...
         +- controller
         |   +- ...
         +- model
         |   +- ...
         +- view
         |   +- ...
```

Existen diferentes formas en que puedes organizar tus paquetes en Java entre ellas un paquete por funcionalidad/característica o por capa cada una con sus respectivas consecuencias.

Te podría servir leer la siguiente publicación [*Project Package Organization*](https://dzone.com/articles/project-package-organization) (*Inglés*) para conocer las ventajas y desventajas de cada orientación.

Si te quedan dudas sobre la organización de clases puedes revisar la definición de paquete (*package*) que brinda Java en su documentación la cual puede ayudarte a darte una idea de como organizar tu aplicación: (*Traducción*)

> Un paquete es un espacio de nombres que organiza un conjunto de clases
>   e interfaces relacionadas. Conceptualmente, puede pensar que los
>   paquetes son similares a diferentes carpetas en su computadora. Puede
>   mantener las páginas HTML en una carpeta, las imágenes en otra y los
>   scripts o aplicaciones en otra. Debido a que el software escrito en el
>   lenguaje de programación Java puede estar compuesto por cientos o
>   miles de clases individuales, tiene sentido mantener las cosas
>   organizadas colocando clases relacionadas e interfaces en paquetes.

**Nota:** Debes recordar que estas son recomendaciones que suelen hacerse para mantener orden en tu proyecto sobre todo cuando están trabajando muchas personas en el y pueden variar dependiendo si es un proyecto pequeño, grande o solo para fines demostrativos.

Por último te dejo estos enlaces donde puedes encontrar información más detallada de los patrones que mencionas.

### Referencias

- [Model-View-Controller](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/model-view-controller/)
- [Data Access Object](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/dao/)
- [*What Is a Package?*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos, crees que ahora que ya tengo todo el código en un controlador, sea "difícil" mover cada código a controladores por separado?

Comment: En general, no pero dependerá de como este tu código. Si tienes problemas en el proceso puedes crear una nueva pregunta explicando tu problema para que se te ayude.